# How to get multiple selected values from a lookup-column using jquery?

Tags: 2013, lookup-column, multi-select

I have a lookUp field named Contractor in my sharepoint list which is multi select box. I am trying to get the values of selected contractor names in SelectCandidate box. PFB my code:

```
var selectedContractors=[];
$("#Contractor_b9ee1d81-a7b7-45ec-bfc6-15c0f8fea99b_AddButton").click(function()
{
$("#Contractor_b9ee1d81-a7b7-45ec-bfc6-15c0f8fea99b_SelectResult :selected").each(function(i,selected)
{
selectedContractors.push($(selected).text());

});
alert(selectedContractors);
});
```

BUt its not working. any help?

Thanks,
Dheeraj

Comment: Can you add the HTML code of your SELECT?

Comment: That is actually a look up field with option to select multiple values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var selectedContractors=[];
$("#Contractor_b9ee1d81-a7b7-45ec-bfc6-15c0f8fea99b_AddButton").click(function()
{
$("#Contractor_b9ee1d81-a7b7-45ec-bfc6-15c0f8fea99b_SelectResult option").each(function()
{
selectedContractors.push($(this).val());

});
alert(selectedContractors);
```

Answer (score 4):

Please refer below code. This works perfectly (In below code I have changed my ID value to the same ID value as yours):

```
$("#Contractor_b9ee1d81-a7b7-45ec-bfc6-15c0f8fea99b_SelectResult option").each(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

**Note:**

Multiselect lookup renders as following(refer below image).[image][image]

**Here we have two sections :**

1. multiselect possible values
2. multiselect selected values

All the options under **2. multiselect selected values** are selected options. So you can directly get all the options from this sections as these are all selected one.